# Python script won't start via bash

Tags: bash

I have this bash script that start the python script ms.py
What is the problem here ?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(ps aux | grep -e 'ms.py$' | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -s "\n") -eq 0 ]; 
then python /root/folder/ms.py &
fi
```

and this in my crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /root/folder/script.sh
```

When I start the script manually it works normal.

Comment: I would make sure your cron user has the necessary programs in the PATH, starting with Python.  Perhaps `/full/path/to/python /root/folder/ms.py`

Comment: I would check the permissions

Comment: I'm trying to do this with putty. Permissions are ok.

Comment: What does your cron debug output says? By default it should email to root@localhost?

Answer (score 1):

you are testing the *output* of that pipeline against the number zero. I assume you want to start your python program only if it's not already running:

```
pid=$(pgrep -f 'ms.py$')
if [[ $pid ]] && kill -0 $pid; then
    echo already running
else
    echo not running
    python /root/folder/ms.py &
fi
```

Comment: `[[ $pid ]]` should be  `[[ "$pid" ]]`. The former won't work if `pgrep` doesn't match -- it will become `[[ ]]`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: @nandhp, not in bash: the double brackets are smart enough to avoid that trap: `x=""; [[ $x ]] && echo y || echo n`